# UIScrollView scroll down

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I am scrolling down a UIscrollView using this method:

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.ScrollForComments.contentSize.height -     self.ScrollForComments.bounds.size.height);
[self.ScrollForComments setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

THe point is that if the content in the UIsecollView is more than the actual size of the scroll view everything works fine, but otherwise if I have less content this method hides everything in the scroll view. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you scroll it if it's too short to scroll? Instead, check to see if the content size is taller than the scroll view size:

```
if (self.ScrollForComments.contentSize.height > self.ScrollForComments.bounds.size.height) {
    // if it is, run your code
    CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.ScrollForComments.contentSize.height - self.ScrollForComments.bounds.size.height);
    [self.ScrollForComments setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
} else {
    // if it is not, either do nothing or scroll to the top
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check that `self.ScrollForComments.contentSize.height -     self.ScrollForComments.bounds.size.height > 0` and if not don't call `setContentOffset`